# How do I build a proper query based on form selections?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to build a proper query based on the form I have, I know how to build a query when all the form values have to be set, but my form has also optional values and I can't really figure out how to do this.

Let's say my form has 4 selects:

```
<select name="1" id="1">
    <option>Select Value</option>
    <option value="rent">rent</option>
    <option value="buy">buy</option>
</select>

<select name="2" id="2">
    <option>Select Value</option>
    <option value="house">house</option>
    <option value="flat">flat</option>
</select>

<select name="3" id="3">
    <option>Swimming pool</option>
    <option value="any">any</option>
    <option value="yes">yes</option>
    <option value="no">no</option>
</select>

<select name="4" id="4">
    <option>Furniture</option>
    <option value="any">any</option>
    <option value="yes">yes</option>
    <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
```

Select 1 & 2 are required, while 3 & 4 are optional and the default value is "any".

My example form submit would be: 1 = rent | 2 = house | 3 = any | 4 = any

What would the proper SELECT query look like ?

I tried so far:

Putting the $_POST value into a variable and then checking with an IF, if the value is "any" I did this:

`if($swimming_pool == 'any') { $swimming_pool = "? OR 1=1"; }`

so the final query would have looked like

`select id from listings WHERE swimming_pool='$swimming_pool'`

which didn't work, not sure if `? OR 1=1` is supposed to select anything ?

I picked that up in another question.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried putting the $_POST value into a variable and then checking with an IF, if the value is "any" I did this: `if($swimming_pool == 'any') { $swimming_pool = "? OR 1=1"; }` so the final query would have looked like `select id from listings WHERE swimming_pool='$swimming_pool'` which didn't work, not sure if `? OR 1=1` is supposed to select anything ? I picked that up in another question.

Comment: edit your question and put your php code there!

Comment: Why not just leave swimming pool out of your query entirely if $_POST[3] == any?

Comment: @DiMono That's what I was thinking, if you could give me an example how I can dynamically build the query that way, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they enter 'any' then you want to leave it out of your query entirely. Basically, build your querystring dynamically before passing it to the database. Something like this (assuming all data has already been cleaned for use in a database query):

```
$where = '1 = 1'

[...]

if ($swimmingpool != 'any')
    $where .= " and swimming_pool = '$swimmingpool'";

if ($furniture != 'any')
    $where .= " and furniture = '$furniture'";

$querystring = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE $where ORDER BY whatever";
// Then pass $querystring when querying the database
```

If you're using a PDO then you should be able to pass your `where` clause as a dynamic array, but this is just a very simple example to help get the ball rolling.